# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout with groupPagingCentered doesn't start centered

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

My layout code is very simple, something that you will have seen in every tutorial or article about the new compositional layouts.

```swift
  func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.93), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    return layout
  }
```

When I start the app, the cell is not properly centered. Only when I drag the cell by the tiniest amount, does it spring to its correct place.

Before:

[image]

After I drag it a tiny bit:

[image]

I have not seen any questions on SO about the same problem. Nobody on Twitter or in blogs talking about it. Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe too late, but here is a workaround:

```
func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, environment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        let sideInset: CGFloat = 5

        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        item.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: sideInset, bottom: 0, trailing: sideInset)

        let groupWidth = environment.container.contentSize.width * 0.93
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(groupWidth), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)

        // add leading and trailing insets to the section so groups are aligned to the center
        let sectionSideInset = (environment.container.contentSize.width - groupWidth) / 2
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: sectionSideInset, bottom: 0, trailing: sectionSideInset)

        // note this is not .groupPagingCentered
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPaging

        return section
    }

    return layout
}
```

Comment: My comment is also quite late haha. But I am working on a new app, ran into the exact same problem, found my old SO question, and now your answer. It works great, thanks!

Comment: This also apparently, solves my issue of centering my cells while not using orthogonal behavior! thanks!

Comment: Glad this helped!

Comment: But groupPaging causing a strange behaviour. When you scroll the last item amd bounce then it scrolls automatically to the previous item

Comment: I wonder what solution Apple used for their Appstore

Comment: @iOSGeek this weird bouncing of the last item seems to be fixed with Xcode 12.5 beta 3

Answer (score 5):

This is expected behavior. "centered" means a cell snaps to the center *after scrolling.* Before doing *any* scrolling, the whole group is scrolled all the way to the right. Your group is only `0.93` fractional width so the difference is slight. The effect is much less unsightly when the fractional width is smaller.

Comment: Hm, that seems weird to me, but your explanation makes sense. Any way to start it off at the correct position?

Comment: I just noticed that even Apple's example code at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/using_collection_view_compositional_layouts_and_diffable_data_sources has the exact same problem. It's so weird to me that they did it like this. It looks buggy.

Comment: Found a way to scroll to the 2nd cell and then to the first cell, when the items are first loaded. That way the first cells shows up in the center. If I don't scroll to the 2nd cell first, it doesn't show up at all until you scroll. So many workarounds 

Answer (score 2):

I found out that if you add Header to you section (even empty on) it solves the problem.

```
let layoutSectionHeaderSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(1.0))
let layoutSectionHeader = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: layoutSectionHeaderSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)
section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [layoutSectionHeader]
```

And yes, you need this:

```
register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader")
```

And provide any empty `UICollectionReusableView` here:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
guard let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader", for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader else {
    fatalError("Could not dequeue SectionHeader")
   }
    return // some empty SectionHeader
}
```

The working sample is [here](https://github.com/nodes-ios/Compositional-Layout-AppStore)

Comment: Wow, this solution makes the problem seem like a bug. Maybe Apple only tested this thing with headers present LOL.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to the first item:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func centerCollectionView() {

    guard collectionView.collectionViewLayout is UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout else { return }
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
}
```

In case the item doesn’t fill the whole screen you will need to scroll to the others, otherwise there is a weird flash. So for instance, if your screen is filled with two items the code would be:

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it visibly jumps into place after the view controller is pushed onto screen. It doesn't look good.

Comment: @KevinRenskers I edited my answer with a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my collectionView-embedded-viewController is embedded in a custom tab bar controller. So when my collectionView was swiped, I sent action to my parent viewController's tab bar button. And it worked.

```
class ChildVC: UIViewController {
    var parentVC: MY_PARENT_VC?
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    // for the first horizontal row
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        parentVC?.MY_CUSTOM_BUTTON.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}

extension ChildVC: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        parentVC?.MY_CUSTOM_BUTTON.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Easy Fix

As suggested in another answer, you can tell the collection view to scroll a certain item to the center. If you do this after the view is visible, the user will see UI moving on its own...not ideal. You can put the item centering code into `viewDidLoad` but it won't work unless you set a very slight delay - I assume you just need to center the cell after the initial layout pass has completed. The code below is working for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // collectionView setup goes here...
     
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) { [self] in
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even later, but I had a similar issue trying to do something similar and this line magically works:

```
section.contentInsetsReference = .readableContent
```

I have literally no idea why it works.  I tried using item.contentInsets, edgeSpacing, everything.  Magically this just worked for me.  Maybe you'll have similar success?

Answer (score -3):

You may want to try this:

[UPCarouselFlowLayout](https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout)

Easy to implement and get the result you need.

Suppose if I want to show banners, using above link you can get the result.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let layout = self.collBannerView.collectionViewLayout as! UPCarouselFlowLayout
            layout.spacingMode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode.fixed(spacing: 10)
            //overlap(visibleOffset: 50)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize.init(width: self.view.frame.width - 70, height: 200)
            self.collBannerView.collectionViewLayout = layout
            let direction: UICollectionView.ScrollDirection = self.orientation.isPortrait ? .horizontal : .vertical
            layout.scrollDirection = direction
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However I specifically want to use UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout :)